# How to change the text of a button when it is being continuosly pressed for 3 seconds

Tags: android, python-3.x, button, kivy, widget

Let's consider the following piece of code:

```
#.py file

class Screen:
    def change_text():
        self.ids.btn.text="some text"
```

```
#.kv file

<Screen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Button:
            id:btn
            on_press: root.change_text()
```

As soon as the button is pressed, its text will be changed. But how can I change the code so that the text is changed only when the button  is continuously pressed for let's say 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the text only after holding the Button down for 3 seconds, you can do something like this:

kv:

```
<Screen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Button:
            id:btn
            on_press: root.start_timer()
            on_release: root.cancel_timer()
```

py:

```
class Screen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.timer = None

    def start_timer(self):
        if self.timer:
            self.timer.cancel()
        self.timer = Clock.schedule_once(self.change_text, 3.0)

    def cancel_timer(self):
        if self.timer:
            self.timer.cancel()

    def change_text(self, dt):
        self.ids.btn.text="some text"
```

This uses `Clock.schedule_once()` to schedule the text change for 3 seconds later. Both the `on_press` and `on_release` cancel any current timer (although it is probably not necessary for the `on_press`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just build some logic in the `Screen` class:

```
class Screen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.start_time = 0
        self.count = 0

    def change_text(self):
        time_now = time.time()
        if time_now - self.start_time > 3.0:
            # longer than 3 seconds since first click, start over
            self.start_time = time_now
            self.count = 1
        else:
            # this click within 3 seconds
            self.count += 1

        if self.count == 3:
            # 3 clicks within 3 seconds, so make the text change
            self.ids.btn.text="some text"
            self.count = 0
            self.start_time = 0
```

Comment: I think I was not clear when asking the question. I meant how can I make the text change only  when I am pressing the button for 3 seconds. Just pressing, not releasing.